# styling list with different image for different levels using :before img

Tags: css, list, bulletedlist

Using a CMS for a webshop.
The platform is currently generateing a list for a menu like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="item*">
  Category 1
    <ul class="level 1">
        <li class="item*">Item 1</li>
        <li class="item*">Item 2</li>
        <li class="item*">Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="item*">Category 2</li>
<li class="item*">Category 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want to add bullets to this list and was thinking of using `li:before` and have a content:url(image.png).

The problem is that I want a diffrent image for the "Categorys" and the "Items"
How can I slove this?

Tried `ul.menu li:before` but that selcets all li in the tree.
The classes that is generated on the li's I dont have mutch control over. The classes generated on the li´s is like "item 1" "item 2" and so on

Is this possible with css or do I need to use jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the space selector to assign your bullet image, which selects all descendants and therefore will add a bullet image to deeper levels too.

Instead, use the **greater-than selector** to select only immediate children. Like this, you only select one level at a time.

```
ul.menu>li:before {
    /* 1st level */
}

ul.menu>li>ul>li:before {
    /* 2nd level */
}

ul.menu>li>ul>li>ul>li ...
```